# Which JDK 8 binary should I install on Raspbian?

Tags: java-8, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to upgrade JDK 8 that came with Raspbian Jessie to the latest version, but there are multiple binaries avaiable on Oracle web site:

1. Java SE Development Kit Linux ARM v6/v7 Hard Float ABI
   (jdk-8u73-linux-**arm32**-vfp-hflt.tar.gz)
2. Java SE Development Kit Linux ARM v6/v7 Hard Float ABI
   (jdk-8u73-linux-**arm64**-vfp-hflt.tar.gz)
3. Java SE Embedded Version 8 Update 73 - ARMv5/ARMv6/ARMv7 Linux -
   SoftFP ABI, Little Endian 2 (ejdk-8u73-linux-arm-sflt.tar.gz)
4. Java SE Embedded Version 8 Update 73 - ARM v6/v7 Linux - VFP, HardFP
   ABI, Little Endian 1 (ejdk-8u73-linux-armv6-vfp-hflt.tar.gz)

Which one is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

I got some answers here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=135941

> Option 1 or 4 is correct for use on a Rasbian system
>   1. Java SE Development Kit Linux ARM v6/v7 Hard Float ABI (jdk-8u73-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz)
>   4. Java SE Embedded Version 8 Update 73 - ARM v6/v7 Linux - VFP, HardFP ABI, Little Endian 1 (ejdk-8u73-linux-armv6-vfp-hflt.tar.gz)
>
> Option 2 requires a 64 bit CPU Option 3 requires a "soft-float" linux
>   system where all applications are compiled *not* to use a floating
>   point VFP unit., it uses a different ABI compared to Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

Go for option 1. Java SE Development Kit Linux ARM v6/v7 Hard Float ABI (jdk-8u73-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz)
stay away from software floating point version, they are very poor performance and you have a hardware floating point calculator in PI so better use it.
Raspbian is a 32 bit operating system , it wont support 64 bit word length JDK or JRE. unless you are on a motorola PC , your architecture is Little Endian